# How to get the color to apper one at a time? (

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I'm doing my best to learn this but I need help :). Thanks in advance.
How can I get the buttons to change color one at a time? Once the button turns red then 2s later the orange button turns on, then 4s later the yellow button and so on until all the buttons are the new color? Here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikole/rrxXN/6/)

```
<div class="interactiveBox">
<button id="root" onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="#ff0000"></button>
<button id="sacral" onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="orange"></button>
<button id="solar" onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="yellow"></button>
<button id="heart" onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="green"></button>
<button id="throat" onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="blue"></button>
<button id="third" onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="purple"></button>
<button id="crown" onclick="changeColor(this)" data-color="white"></button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeColor(obj) {
//reset other buttons
 var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){      
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000000" ;
    }
    obj.style.backgroundColor=obj.getAttribute('data-color');
    if(obj.id == "root"){
        setTimeout(changeAllcolors,2000);
    }
}
function changeAllcolors(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
        var color = buttons[i].getAttribute('data-color');
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rrxXN/11/) with a slightly different approach. I'm not sure I got the timing exactly as you want it, but you can change it easily.

JS

```
var timer;
var light = 1;

colorarray = new Array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'pink', 'green', 'chocolate', 'cyan');

function timedCount()
{
  timer = setTimeout(function(){timedCount()},500*light);
  $(".interactiveBox div:nth-child("+ light +")").css('background-color', colorarray[light]);
  light = light + 1;
  if(light>8)
  {
   light = 1;
   $('.interactiveBox div').css( 'background-color', 'white');
   }
}

$('.start').click(function(){
      timedCount();
});

$('.stop').click(function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this JQuery as well?

Comment: Yes, with .css, it's jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The function called by *setTimeout* needs to know which button has just been set, change the colour of the next one, then call itself again until it's changed all the buttons. You could use the NodeList returned by getElementsByTagName for that, e.g.

```
function changeAllcolors(){
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  var i = 0;

  var changeNext = function (){
    if (++i < buttons.length) {
      buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = buttons[i].getAttribute('data-color');
      setTimeout(changeNext, 2000);
    }
  };
  changeNext();
}
```

You should also make the value returned by *setTimeout* available to *changeColor* so that it can call *clearTimeout* to stop the colours changing. At the moment, they will keep changing colours and clicking  *root* multiple times will kick of multiple timers. So you might get some wierd behaviour if someone does lots of clicking on lots of buttons.

Comment: Both answers are great. Thanks for helping me.